# Create a static (not redrawn everytime I zoom, or move around) plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am rather new to python in general, but have found it very useful and much more intuitive than other programming languages.

I'm currently trying to plot a spectrum with a lot of data points, and it seems that every time I move around, zoom in our out, matplotlib redraws the figure, which takes some time (5 to 20 seconds every time I move).

This makes scanning through the spectrum pretty tedious, and I was thinking if maybe I could find a way to create the figure once and for all, and then just show a part of it, and move around in the static figure, without redrawing it, that would save me a lot of idle time.

My question is this : is there a (reasonably easy) way to do this in matplotlib or should I start looking into other plotting software ?
I've looked around in the documentation but to be honest, I don't understand most of it.

Thanks for the input !

Cheers

In case anyone is wondering, here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def show_shifted_lines(z, nb_lines, color='red'):
    # Draws a vertical line with its name at the location 
    # of the line (shifted by (1+z) )

    # Writes the name of the line
    for i in range(nb_lines):
        plt.text(rest_wl[i]*(1.+z), 200., line_name[i], color=color, rotation=50, rotation_mode='anchor')
        # Writes the vertical line
        for j in range(20):
            plt.text(rest_wl[i]*(1.+z), 190-8*j, '|', color=color)
    return 

f = open('spectrum.dat', 'r')

## Plot Spectrum ##
wavelength = []
flux = []
for line in f :
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    wavelength.append(float(columns[0]))
    flux.append(float(columns[1]))
flux = np.asarray(flux, dtype=float)
wavelength = np.asarray(wavelength, dtype=float)
plt.plot(wavelength, flux, color='black')
plt.xlabel(r'Wavelength (A)')
plt.ylabel(r'Flux (erg s$^{-1}$ cm$^{-2}$ A$^{-1}$)')
plt.grid(True)
f.close()


## Show location of redshifted lines ##    
f = open('list_of_restframe_lines.txt','r')
line_name  = []
rest_wl    = []
# Redshifts of various absorption-line systems 
z1  = 3.04976
z2  = 2.27831
z3  = 1.80335
z4  = 2.218
z5  = 2.2155
z6  = 2.2164
z7  = 2.8913

# Create array for not-shifted lines
for line in f :
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    line_name.append(columns[0])
    rest_wl.append(float(columns[1]))
rest_wl = np.asarray(rest_wl, dtype=float)  
f.close()

show_shifted_lines(z1, len(rest_wl))
show_shifted_lines(z2, len(rest_wl), 'magenta')
show_shifted_lines(z3, len(rest_wl), 'lightgreen')
show_shifted_lines(z4, len(rest_wl), 'green')
show_shifted_lines(z5, len(rest_wl), 'darkorange')
show_shifted_lines(z6, len(rest_wl), 'orange')
show_shifted_lines(z7, len(rest_wl), 'blue')

plt.show()
```

Ultimately, my spectrum looks something like this : [Example of small part of a spectrum with redshifted absorbing systems shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYE6G.png)

Comment: i don't think that link has anything to do with what you are asking. Its about making figures for the `matplotlib` documentation.

Comment: I don't know about your question but I would like to point out that numpy has an excellent function for importing csv called genfromtxt()

Comment: Have you taken a look at this functionality? It creates an [svg that can be modified in a web-browser](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/user_interfaces/svg_histogram.html).

Comment: Oh, thanks tom, that's probably why it made no sense to me.
Achim, I think what you're suggesting is to read my inputfiles faster? 
Thank you, I'll take note of it, but indeed, it doesn't help me with my question.
And Schorsch, after looking at the link, it seems this is also an interactive figure, which doesn't help me much. But thanks for the input.